# Unity - Spawning Objects from Array in a grid causing duplicates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid, spawn

I'm attempting to spawn all available prefabs into a grid to view them easier. Basically as a tool to pick and choose various building parts to make custom buildings (specficially using SyntyStudios packages if that info helps)

I'm able to grab all the assets I want and make an array, that isn't the issue. When I try and step through each object in the array and spawn them into their "grid position" my code is spawning the same object at each position, before moving to the next object.

This is my code as it stands:

```
                for(int a = 0; a < allPrefabs.Count; a++)
                    SpawnAssets(allPrefabs[a]);
```

That builds my array, which again, works just fine as far as I can tell (it does populate in the inspector)

```
    void SpawnAssets(GameObject obj)
    {
        spawnPos = Vector3.zero;
        Debug.Log("Spawn Mechanic v5");
        int width = allPrefabs.Count/2;
        int depth = allPrefabs.Count/2;
        for(int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                GameObject assetClone = Instantiate(obj,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
                Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(x*offsetDistance,0,z*offsetDistance);
                assetClone.transform.position = spawnPos;
                assetClone.transform.parent = parentObj;
            }
    }
```

That code is where I believe the issue lies. I can move the Instantiate out of the 'for' loops and remove the duplication but it just iterates through the position, and then all my assets are on top of each other in the last position.

I've looked over the documentation, followed a number of YouTube tutorials and nothing seems to fix this and I'm clearly blind to the error because it looks like I'm doing the exact same thing as they (documentation and YT) are.

I would love another set of eyes on this to help me point out what is no doubt a very silly oversight on my part. Thanks very much for your time!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGsZ1.jpg
EDIT
This is an image of the duplication issue I get. Each item is spawned 39 times (there are 39 prefabs available when the array is built, so its instantiating the same prefab as many times as they array is long, if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand the exact behavior you are expecting.

Currently it is no wonder that all prefabs are in all positions because this is exactly what you tell it to do.

- You iterate over all existing prefabs
- You take this current prefab and spawn it onto every position in the grid in `SpawnAssets`

---

If I understand you correct what you want is to generate a (as square as possible) grid where each prefab is spawned exactly **once**.

```c#
private void Start()
{
    SpawnAssets(allPrefabs);
}

void SpawnAssets(List<GameObject> obj)
{
    // You do NOT want to divide the amount of prefabs by 2
    // A grid has dimensions x * y ... not x + y!
    
    // You want the square root of the amount of all prefabs
    // but rounded up to the next full number
    var width = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(allPrefabs.Count));

    // Then you want the second dimension so simply divide the entire amount by the 
    // previously calculated width, then again round up to the next full number
    var depth = Mathf.CeilToInt(allPrefabs.Count / (float) width);

    // have only ONE counter for the created objects
    for (var i = 0; i < allPrefabs.Count; i++)
    {
        // Calculate x and z indices from the one given index
        // depends a bit on how you want to lay out the prefabs 
        // you can easily exchange whether you want to dive/modulo by "depth" or "width"
        // you can also exchange whether you want to use division/modulo for "z" or "x"
        var z = i / depth;
        var x = i % depth;

        var spawnPos = new Vector3(x * offsetDistance, 0, z * offsetDistance);
        var assetClone = Instantiate(obj[i], spawnPos, Quaternion.identity, parentObj);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. There it is. I knew it was doing what it was being told to do but for the life of me, i couldn't wrap my head around getting it the way I wanted it. You did exactly that. Thank you very much and I'm sorry it was difficult to understand but you nailed it perfectly. Thank you again very much!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see on the fly, is that you practically instantiate your objects in a nested loop. That will definitely result in multiple objects.

Think of it like this. Each time you want to instantiate an object, you go through the entire grid and place an object on each grid position. Then, you go to the next object and do the same.

Maybe you forgot an if statement to check whether you should actually instantiate or not.

Or, you can try setting the last instantiated position on an external variable (probably vector3) and use that to determine the new one.